# Is there a way to script the "Execute Groovy script" in jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

[image: Execute Groovy Script]

This is what I have so far but unsure this is the correct way to invoke a groovy script in the workspace with parameters.

```
stage ('Load Groovy Script') {
        agent {node 'test'}
          steps {
              def script = load("${env.WORKSPACE}/test.groovy")
              script.method(--sourceDir ${env.WORKSPACE}/test})
          }
     }
```

Comment: Wrap the scripts within a `script {}` block as in `steps { script { def script = ... } }`.

Comment: Thanks @DibakarAditya. it loads the groovy script now but the env variables are not recognized. How to define the script parameters like we do in a jenkins job? need to script the execute groovy scripts like in the screenshot attached.

Comment: change `script.method(--sourceDir ${env.WORKSPACE}/test})` to `script.method(--sourceDir "${env.WORKSPACE}/test}")`

Comment: @yong thanks, I ended up using sh command to execute the groovy script.